# Tree View only last level nodes has to be removed when the first level node is clicked in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Whenever, I click the checkbox, then, it contains any child 'UL' and this 'LI' is the last, then, I need copy this UL childs only 'SPAN' need to copy and paste the same to destination folder. I tried the below code.

Aim: Whenever, i press the checkbox it contains any child ul and if it last one, then, it should be copied.

On this list, If I click `Node 1.1.1', Node 1.1.2 etc`, then, it should copy only Node 1.1.1, Node 1.1.2 etc

On this list, If I click, `Node 1.1`, then, it should copy only Node 1.1.1, Node 1.1.2 etc.

On this list, If I click, `Node 1.2, Node 1.3 etc[Here It does not have descendant]`, then, it should copy only Node 1.2, Node 1.3 etc. Not 'Node 1.1' because it has descendant.

On this list, If I click, `'Node 1'`, then, it should copy 
`Node 1.1.1, Node 1.1.2, Node 1.1.3, Node 1.1.4 and Node 1.1.5`  then
`Node 1.2[not 1.1 because it has descendant], Node 1.3, Node 1.4, Node 1.5 and Node 1.6`

Any Idea? Please.

```
<div class="form-group floatleft10" id="tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Node 1" /><span>Node 1</span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Node 1.1" /><span>Node 1.1</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Node 1.1.1" /><span>Node 1.1.1</span></li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Node 1.1.2" /><span>Node 1.1.2</span></li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Node 1.1.3" /><span>Node 1.1.3</span></li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Node 1.1.4" /><span>Node 1.1.4</span></li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Node 1.1.5" /><span>Node 1.1.5</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Node 1.2" /><span>Node 1.2</span>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Node 1.3" /><span>Node 1.3</span>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Node 1.4" /><span>Node 1.4</span>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Node 1.5" /><span>Node 1.5</span>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Node 1.6" /><span>Node 1.6</span>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Node 2" /><span>Node 2</span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Node 2.1" /><span>Node 2.1</span>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Node 2.2" /><span>Node 2.2</span>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="form-group floatleft13" id="checkbox-content"></div>
```

Jquery

```
(function ($) {

    $('div#tree input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {

        var $list = $("div#checkbox-content");
        var $currElem = $(this).clone();
        var $currElemNext = $(this).next().clone();
        var $curElemVal = $(this).attr("value");
        var $curElemValAdd = "";
        var $curElemValNext = $(this).next().text();
        if ($(this).parent().children("ul").children("li").prop('tagName') == undefined && $(this).parent().children("ul").prop('tagName') == undefined) {
            console.log($(this).val());
            $list.append($('<div data-value="' + $(this).val() + '"></div>').append($currElemNext));
            var $thisTempAdd = $(this).val();
            var $currElemSiblngs = $(this).parent().clone();
            //$currElemSiblngs.find(":checkbox").remove();
            var newCopiedElements = $currElemSiblngs.find("span.daredevel-tree-label").clone();
            var $tempVal = $(this).html();
            //$curElemValAdd += '<div class="try"><span>'+ $tempVal +'</span></div>';
            console.log("Here");
            $list.find("div").filter(function () { return $(this).data('value') === $thisTempAdd });
        }
            /// Second Level

        else if ($(this).parent().children("ul").children("li").prop('tagName') == "LI" && $(this).parent().children("ul").prop('tagName') == "UL") {
            //console.log();
            var $currParent = $(this).parent().prop('tagName');
            if ($(this).parent().has('ul') && $(this).parent().children('ul').parent().prop('tagName') == $currParent) {
                console.log("dshdsdhdd");
                var $currElemSiblngs = $(this).parent().children('ul').children("li");
                //$currElemSiblngs.find(":checkbox").remove();
                var newCopiedElements = $currElemSiblngs.find("span.daredevel-tree-label").clone();
                var $curElemValAdd = "";
                $(newCopiedElements).each(function () {
                    var $tempVal = $(this).html();
                    console.log($(this).text());
                    $curElemValAdd += '<div data-value="' + $(this).text() + '"><span>' + $tempVal + '</span></div>';

                });
                $list.append($curElemValAdd);
            }
        }
            /// First Level
        else if ($(this).parent().children("ul").children("li").children("ul").children("li").prop('tagName') == "LI") {
            var $currParent = $(this).parent().prop('tagName');
            if ($(this).parent().children("ul").children("li").children("ul") && $(this).parent().children("ul").children("li").children("ul").children("li").prop('tagName') == $currParent) {
                console.log("dshdsdhddHHHHHHHHHHH");
                var $currElemSiblngs = $(this).parent().children("ul").children("li").children("ul");
                //$currElemSiblngs.find(":checkbox").remove();
                var newCopiedElements = $currElemSiblngs.find("span.daredevel-tree-label").clone();
                var $curElemValAdd = "";
                $(newCopiedElements).each(function () {
                    var $tempVal = $(this).html();
                    console.log($(this).text());
                    $curElemValAdd += '<div data-value="' + $(this).text() + '"><span>' + $tempVal + '</span></div>';

                });
                $list.append($curElemValAdd);
            }

        } else if (!this.checked) {
            //alert("new function");
            var thisTemp = $(this).val();
            //console.log(thisTemp);
            $list.find("div").filter(function () { return $(this).data('value') === thisTemp }).remove();
        }
        else if (this.checked) {
            $list.append($('<div></div>').append($currElemNext));
            //$list.append($currElemNext);
        } else {
            //hide to the right
            $list.find('span').filter(function () {
                console.log($curElemVal);
                console.log($curElemValAdd);
                return ($(this).text() === $curElemVal || $(this).text() === $curElemValAdd)
            }).slideUp("fast", function () {
                //$(this).next('span').remove();
                $(this).remove();
                //alert("2");
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you please try to express yourself more clearly? What is the expected behaviour? Please provide the community with a few use cases! Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/167bqchz/

Comment: @bernland, Yes, I made my statement bit clearly here https://jsfiddle.net/167bqchz/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***UPDATE***

Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/b36921na/3/

```
(function ($) {

    $('div#tree input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
        $('#checkbox-content').text('');
        printNodeValues($(this));

    });

})(jQuery);

function printNodeValues(element) {

    if (element.parent().children('ul').length > 0) {
        element.parent().children('ul').children('li').each(function() {
            printNodeValues($(this).children('input'));
        });  
    } else {
        $('#checkbox-content').html($('#checkbox-content').html() + "<br />" + element.val());
    }
}
```

The above code uses recursion. If this is not what you have been looking for, then please let me know what exactly is supposed to happen when clicking Node 1, Node 1.1, Node 1.1.1, ..., Node 1.1.5, Node 1.2, ..., Node 1.6, Node 2, Node 2.1, and Node 2.2 and I will be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks for this! Still it needs some additonal code. I made my comments on this post just after 'Aim'. Please refer that. Also, could you please do the remove function from the copied folder. I mean I should remove the same those copied to div when i uncheck the same input checkbox. Please